# Executing Python script in Azure ML studio

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I wanted to create a webservice which will provide a summary of texts in the given URL using python , beautifulsoup and nltk.

However I encounter the following error in Azure ML Studio

**Schematics in AZURE:**

[image: Azure Schematics]

[image]

EnterData Module is having URL from wiki

Execute Python Script is having following code

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def azureml_main(dataframe1="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics", dataframe2 = None):
    wiki = dataframe1[0].to_string()
    page = ur.urlopen(wiki)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    df= pd.DataFrame([soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text()], columns =['article_text'])
    return dataframe1,
```

Running this experiment producing  following error:

```
    Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
    ---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
    Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1876, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(key)
        File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4027)
      File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3891)
      File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
      File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
    KeyError: 0
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
        odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
      File "C:\temp\84d7e9fbcfe54596a2e7de022b4d236c.py", line 23, in azureml_main
        wiki = dataframe1[0][0].to_string()
      File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1992, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1999, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1345, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3225, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1878, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4027)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3891)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: 0
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ----------
Start time: UTC 11/11/2018 15:34:21
End time: UTC 11/11/2018 15:34:30
```

1. I am using Anaconda 4.0/Python 3.5 to run this snippet.
2. when I assign the URL to the variable wiki, the code runs successfully in my local machine
3. I am not sure why I cannot fetch the value from the input dataframe1.
4. Input dataframe is not having header hence dataframe1[0] should fetch the URL directly..

Thanks to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

your `dataframe1` is look like this

```
dataframe1 = {'Col1' : ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method']}
```

the key is not index (int), but its `'Col1'`, you can fix it with

```
wiki = dataframe1['Col1'].to_string(index=0)
```

but it raise another error, the URL is trimmed if too long

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element....
```

so it better using

```
wiki = dataframe1['Col1'][0]
```

another error is

```
return dataframe1,
```

it should be

```
return df,
```

fixed code

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def azureml_main(dataframe1="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics", dataframe2 = None):
    wiki = dataframe1['Col1'][0]
    page = ur.urlopen(wiki)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    df= pd.DataFrame([soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text()], columns=['article_text'])
    return df,
```

Comment: ur welcome, please consider mark the answer correct.